# Prompt user with a text before entering values on terminal in Fortran

Tags: fortran

I would like to know how to make fortran ask me to enter a value (from a loop) on the screen, I mean, I have a simple loop (inside the script):

```
if (ns.eq.1) then
 f(i,n+1)=5*sign(1.,(20-(x-c*t))*((x-c*t)-10))
 elseif (ns.eq.2) then
  f(i,n+1)=(1-mu)*f(i,n)+(mu*f(i-1,n))

endif
   enddo
```

And I want to appear on the (terminal) (when I do gfortran... etc.)
'Enter a value of ns'
so that I can put 1 and it plots the first case and if I put 2, it brigs me the 2nd plot
I tried with

```
write(*,*)'Enter a value of ns'   
read(*,*) ns
```

But it didn't work

Comment: Hi, did you try to output `ns` after you read it using `write(*,*) ns`. What does it return. Further more, how did you declare `ns`? I think we need to see a bit more of your code (simplified) to have a better chance of helping you out.

Comment: Welcome, be sure to take the [tour]. Never say "it didn't work", it is useless. Say what happened. Did it crash? Any error messages? How did they look like? Something else happened? What exactly? What was printed instead? See [ask] and [edit] your question to show more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What will probably work is:

```
write (*,'(A)',advance='no') 'Enter a value of ns '
read (*,*) ns
```

There's no guarantee in the Fortran standard that this will do what you want, but pretty much every implementation does.

Comment: this improves the look, but isnt necessary. The original code should work as is..